# Get objects on OnCollisionEnter2D event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a method `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)`, when 2 objects make collision, how can I get this 2 objects (classes)? Thanks.

Comment: Never really used unity but [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) suggests `coll.Colider` and `coll.gameObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function on GameObject can be used to get objects of a specified type that belong to a particular GameObject.

In your case you'd want `coll.gameObject.GetComponent<T>()` where T is the type of the object you want to get. Be aware that it may return `null` though.